# Move the line in canvas - problems

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i tryied to move line object in my app.

Xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="300" Width="350" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" Background="Transparent" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

  if (e.OriginalSource is Line)
        {
            linia = (Line)e.OriginalSource;
            if(!LineFocus)
                LineFocus = true;
            return;
        }
   else
     LineFocus = false;
}
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
  TranslateTransform ruch = new TranslateTransform(pos.X - startPoint.X, pos.Y - startPoint.Y);
  linia.RenderTransform = ruch;
}
```

It works fine my line is moved, but when I try to move it again it is moving from oryginal place (the place when i draw them at the very first time).
When I checked it by MessageBox() with this:

```
...
linia = (Line)e.OriginalSource;
MessageBox.Show(linia.X1 + linia.Y1 + linia.X2 + linia.Y2);
...
```

Allways return exactly the same values even after move, so what is the reason of that?

Comment: Because a Translate does not 'move' an item, just renders it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are my edits:

First you need two Points: a start point(startPoint) and an end point(pos).
In the move handler you set the newPoint to the current mouse position relative to the canvas.
Then you take the difference between the newPoint and the oldPoint, you get two variables: dX and dY. Now you add these differences to the Points of the line, and finally make the new point to the next start point:

```
pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
double dX = pos.X - startPoint.X;
double dy = pos.Y - startPoint.Y;
//if you want, you can put here an if- statement to check if the mouse is down
linia.X1 += dX;
linia.X2 += dX;
linia.Y1 += dY;
linia.Y2 += dY;
//Here comes the end of the if
startPoint = pos;
```

Hope this helped you!

Supose you want to change the position on 2 steps:

The Line is like this:

X1 = 70

X2 = 80

Y1 = 70

Y2 = 80

You move the mouse by x=1 and y=1

pos = (71, 81)

startPoint = (70, 80)

**1. step:**

X1 = 70 + 71 - 70 = 71
The same with the other values

The line is like this:

X1 = 71

X2 = 81

Y1 = 71

Y2 = 81

**Now set the value of startPoint to the value of pos:**

**startPoint = (71, 81)**

**2. step**

startPoint = (71, 81)
pos = (72, 82) //You move the mouse by 1 and 1

This will get a line like this:

X1 = 71 + 72 - 71 = 72

X2 = 71 + 72 - 71 = 72

Y1 = 81 + 82 - 81 = 82

Y2 = 81 + 82 - 81 = 82

And so on...

Comment: I dont understund what u trying to tell me with this code, but its kind of joke i think ?

Comment: No, not at all! This codes just changes the **position** of the line and not the Transform. Replace `TranslateTransform ruch = new TranslateTransform(pos.X - startPoint.X, pos.Y - startPoint.Y);` with my code and it should work. (Note, I did some changes on my answer)

Comment: My code could not work because I don't had all your code, so please post some more.

Comment: look it dont works bcus lets take a look at that:
line with: 70 70 80 80 Cords. We want to move it by 5. on X. So it should be 75 70 85 80.
Lets take a look what your code will do. It will be 4 steps bcus it changing in every 1 cord.
Step 1. X1 = 70 + 71 - 70 = 71
Step 2. X1 = 71 + 72 - 70 = 73
Step 3. X1 = 73 + 74 - 70 = 77
Step 4. X1 = 77 + 75 - 70 = 82 So this code just cant work at all... Doesn't matters about other code in app. It cant work good. Just take some piece of paper and calculate it.

Comment: You forgot to set the new Pos to the next old position(Look at the last line of code)

Comment: Thanks this solution works fine, but I wanted to use affine transform, bcus i need to make rotation etc as well. Anyway thanks man :)